# How can i generate 100.000 6 digits unique number into a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to gender 100000 different 6 digits numbers with php and put into a mysql table with just one row called UiD..

How can i do this?

I have this code to generate 6 digits and 100000 of them, but i just cant figure out how to put them in mysql.. :

```
<?
$n=range(100000,999999); //100.000 - 999.999
shuffle($n);
for ($x=0; $x< 100000; $x++)
{
 echo $n[$x].' '; //SHOULD I DO THE MYSQL CODE HERE FOR INSERTING INTO DB?? And if so, how?
}

?>
```

...and does this render unique numbers?
So i want have the same number twice or more?
How could i render unique numbers, if this code don't?

Hope you guys understand what i mean..

Best regards.

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: If you don’t know how to insert data using PHP & MySQL _at all_ - then you should not come here asking us overly broad questions, but go read up on that in some beginner tutorial.

Comment: _“and does this render unique numbers?”_ - yes, because it just picks values out of a shuffled array. The values in that array are unique to begin with.

Comment: Well i do know a little php and mysql.. but i'm no expert..
So that's why i'm asking you folk's.. to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to be random? If not, just do a foor loop 100000 times and add 1 to the previous iteration's number.
Like this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$number = 100000;
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $number = $number + 1;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (UiD) VALUES ($number)";
    $conn->query($sql)
} 
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, but i figured it out...

I just needed a break, some coffee and fresh air ;)
Thank's again..